# MYSQL - Select Query Where condition refer to same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like :

tblA

```
code    |    name    |    parent_code  | status    | child
---------------------------------------------------------
1       | ABC        |                 | complete  | N
1.1     | ABC.1      | 1               | pending   | Y
2       | BCD        |                 | pending   | N
2.1     | BCD.1      | 2               | pending   | Y
```

I am trying to get the record with `child = Y` and its parent `status = complete`

This is the output i am trying to get

```
code    |    name    |    parent_code  | status    | child
----------------------------------------------------------
1.1     | ABC.1      | 1               | pending   | Y
```

So far, the method i am using is query all the record with `child=Y` and looping again to get the status of each `code` base on the `parent_code` from previous query.

Is it possible to make the query more simple?

Comment: Add the output table which you are expecting

Comment: @Jens what you mean by parent status? the parent itself will not have a `parent_code` because they are a parent

Comment: @JosephGoh i refer to your question: `its parent status = complete`

Comment: @Jens, ah okay, a typo there, i have update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one.

```
SELECT C.*
    FROM tblA C
    INNER JOIN tblA P ON P.code = C.parent_code
    WHERE C.child = 'Y'
        AND P.status = 'complete'
```

Answer (score 1):

A self join should do the work:

```
SELECT child.*
from tblA child join tblA parent on child.parent_code =parent.code
WHERE parent.child = 'N' and parent.status = 'complete'
```

Comment: thank you for your `self join`, never know that i can join to table itself, but i have to choose for the answer that near to what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code,  name ,  parent_code,status, child
from tblA
WHERE child = 'Y' and status = 'PENDING'

pl. try i am not sure about your resultset
```

Comment: Your code is not checking the status of parent at all